# Spree Product Property value saved like "--- Value\n...\n" in DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, csv, spree

I did rake task to populate my spree database with some sample data, and now when I try to look for Product Property like: `Spree::ProductProperty.where(value: 'Value')` I get `[]`. I checked database row with GUI and all product properties values are saved like `"--- Value\n...\n"` and when I search for records with: `Spree::ProductProperty.where(value: '--- Value\n...\n')` I get what I should get with the first one.

My rake task:

```
namespace :initial_data do
  desc 'Initial Data Load'
  task load: :environment do
    add_product_properties
  end
end

def add_product_properties
  puts 'Adding Product Properties...'
  require 'csv'
  products_properties_csv = File.read(Rails.root.join('lib/assets/products_properties_list.csv'))
  products_properties = CSV.parse(products_properties_csv, headers: true)

  type = Spree::Property.create(name: 'Type', presentation: 'Type')
  products_properties.each_with_index do |row|
    Spree::ProductProperty.create!(value: row['type'], product: Spree::Product.joins(:translations).find_by!(slug: row['handle']), property: type)
  end
end
```

My CSV file:

```
handle,type
slug-slug-slug,Greeting Card
slug-slug-slug-2,Greeting Card
slug-slug-slug-3,Greeting Card
another-slug,Tote
slug-sth-else,Cover
slug-vendor-name,Clutch
```

I use branch `3-0-stable` of Spree gem.

I wonder why it is like so. And my question is how can I fix that?

Thanks guys a lot for your time.

Comment: That's YAML inside your database. Are you sure `row['type']` is what you expect it to be? And why use `each_with_index` when you're not using the index?

Comment: @muistooshort Actually I use index to indicate how long I need to wait for the process to finish, just removed line to avoid additional complications. I am sure it's what I expect it to be, and when I tested it with `row['type'].class` it returned String. BTW, it happens only for Product::Property model. Why is it saved as YAML?

Comment: I don't use Spree so I don't know what `Spree::ProductProperty` is doing. Odds are its using `serialize` to allow people to lazily store anything in `value`, if that's the case then you can't query `value` in any useful way.

Comment: I found out I could search for Properties with: `Spree::ProductProperty.where(value: 'Value'.to_yaml)`. The strange thing is there is no code responsible for ProductProperty value convertion/serialization in Spree gem source. At least I can't find it... 
Anyway, thanks @muistooshort